# Sorting Java script object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an object like below.

```js
var obj = {};
obj['key_1'] = ["2016-07-02","100","1"];
obj['key_2'] = ["2016-06-02","100","1"];
```

I want to sort the object by date in ascending order.

Can some one help me how to sort that object

Comment: Objects properties don't have an order. If it's important for the elements to be in a particular order use an array instead. Or iterate over `Object.keys(obj).sort(/*suitable sort function here*/)`.

Comment: finding out how to write sort function...